# Updating written text to view while typing

Tags: javascript, c#, html

We all know StackOverFlow's system, which basically enables you to see what your written text look like while sending a question.

I'm looking to create this as well on my website, and I would like something to start with.

I obviously don't expect you to write that code for me, but to explain a bit what do I need for that and how would that work.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking for help with specific code-related problems. please consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alright, I understand. Any suggestion where I can go with that question, though?

Comment: http://codingforums.com/ maybe? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Using vanilla js instead of jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/wmjnaj6n/4/

## HTML

```
<input type='text' id='input'>
<div id='update'></div>
```

## Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById('input');
var target = document.getElementById('update');
element.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    target.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

---

For completeness, the jquery way would be:

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
       //do stuff here
       $('#update').text( $(this).val() ); 
});
```

Comment: I'm actually not using JQuery. Didn't mention that, my bad.

Comment: @albertmachilov: sorry but in all, yours is a very incomplete question. You will want to show the results of your researches and efforts with your question and ask a much more specific question.

Comment: I guess that's fair. I'll try to work this out myself. Thanks, though.